# Show different menu links to user depending upon their Drupal 6 role

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-6, hyperlink

I want to display different navigation links and data to a user depending upon their role.

What module(s) could I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_menu_alter/6)()

```
/*
* Implementation of hook_menu_alter()
*/
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items)
{
   $items['your/path']['access callback'] = _custom_access_callback_for_this_page();
}
```

And inside the access callback function (here: `_custom_access_callback_for_this_page`), write whatever the validation you want.

Don't forget to clear the cache after any changes inside your `hook_menu_alter() implementation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I really like this module for `Drupal 6`, you should check it out:
[Menu per Role](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role)